# sfdx error while running in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, salesforce, jenkins-pipeline

Can anyone help me this issue in sfdx. I was able to execute scratch org and package version creation using Jenkinsfile. But getting an error while installing metadata on scratch org and sandbox.

```
[Pipeline] sh
[SFDX_SFDX_Package_Installation] Running shell script
+ sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package sfdx_naresh@0.1.0-1 -k nar123 -r -u scratchorg@so7.org             
autoupdate:: /root/.cache/sfdx/update.lock is locked with an active 
writer
ERROR:  INVALID_HEADER_TYPE.
[Pipeline] error
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Package Installing Failed
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: From the error it looks like maybe some kind of error with a rest command. Can you give more details as to what your script/code looks like?

Comment: my script is written in Groovy language.
rc = sh returnStatus: true, script: "sfdx force:package:install --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --package ${PACKAGE_NAME} -k ${INSTALLATION_KEY} -u ${SCRATCHORG_NAME}"
            if (rc != 0) { 
    error 'Package Installing Failed' 
   }